# How to create excel sheets visible only by the author

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have the following macro in excel, and I would like to modify somehow that only the 'author' can open a particular sheet. I mean that when I create a new excel file it will show that author xyz, so I want to do it that I can only see the xyz sheet, and if user 1 can only see a sheet named user 1, etc... Is it possible anyhow?

```
  Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim pword As String
On Error GoTo endit
    pword = InputBox("Enter Your Identification Number")
    Select Case pword
      Case Is = "Test": Sheets("Test").Visible = True
      Case Is = "1": Sheets("User1").Visible = True
      Case Is = "2": Sheets("User2").Visible = True
      Case Is = "showallthesheets": Call UnHideAllSheets
End Select
Sheets("Dummy").Visible = False
Exit Sub
endit:
MsgBox "Incorrect Password"
End Sub
```

However all the sheets should be visible with one code lets say (here I used 'showallthesheets'), and with this code I should be able to create more sheets if needed and just like before if I name a sheet user 55 then only user 55 should be able to open.

Comment: Honestly, if you've gotten to this point in an Excel spreadsheet, then you've made a fundamental error somewhere in your overall technical architecture. What you're building is _no longer_ a spreadsheet, but a fully-featured application, and should be viewed (and implemented) as such.

Comment: I would hide all the sheets in the begining, use `Environ (Username)` to check username and compare it in separate table with `VLOOKUP` to determine name of required sheet and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of the following, where the possible ids are kept in an array and you loop the array, checking if it matches the pword entered. It means you don't need a long list of test conditions. Write the test once and use a loop.

That said, as you are building something quite involved there are things like error handling to consider, when to lock structure of workbook, validating user input etc.

I think though you will need some code that gets the current username `Environ$("Username")` and uses that in some form of additional validation as any user could enter id 1 etc.

I am not sure how this situation applies to creating new files as these sheets will not exist to unhide. I think to deal with that part of the question more clarification is required.

```
Sub UnhideSheets()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim idArr()
    Dim pword As String
    Dim id As Long
    Dim Found as Boolean

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Found = False
    idArr = Array("Test","1","2","showallthesheets") ' extend as appropriate
    pword = InputBox("Enter your identification number")

    For id = LBound(idArr) to UBound(idArr)
        If pword = idArr(id) Then
            Found = True
            If LCase(pword) = "showallthesheets" Then
               'assumes protected and you decide when protect again e.g. upon close event
                wb.Protect Structure:=False, Password:="password"
                UnhideAllSheets
           Else
               wb.Sheets("User" & idArr(id)).Visible = True
           End If   
        End If
    Next id     

    If Not Found Then MsgBox("Incorrect Password")

End Sub
```